# How to make sub for Picture box made during Run time in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, click, picturebox

So I have a button, and when the button is clicked, a picture box is created. I just wanted to know how I can make a message box appear when I click on that newly created picturebox.

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(p);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add a click event to your picturebox

```
p.MouseClick += p_MouseClick;
```

after adding a event this function will be called on that event -

```
void p_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{      
       MessageBox.Show("clicked");
}
```

Comment: Add a note on the `sender` object: it's the actual PictureBox that was clicked, so you can cast `sender` to PictureBox and access its properties (e.g., `(sender as PictureBox).Image = new Bitmap(...);`).